# HTML5 inheritance (tags?) issue

Tags: html

I want to create lightbox structure in HTML5.

Here's my code:

```
<p>
   <a href="images/1.jpg" class="lightbox">
      <img src="images/1.jpg" style="width: 320px; height: 200px" alt="" />
      <div class="zoom">Zoom.</div>
      test test
   </a>
   Paragraph text.        
</p>
```

Now, the "zoom" div along with "test test" text should be children of link called "lightbox", but browsers render above code as three separate links (how it's even possible?):

```
<p>
   <a href="images/1.jpg" class="lightbox">
      <img src="images/1.jpg" style="width: 320px; height: 200px" alt=""/>
   </a>
</p>
<div class="zoom">
   <a href="images/1.jpg" class="lightbox">Zoom.</a>
</div>
<a href="images/1.jpg" class="lightbox"> test test </a>
   Text 
<p/>
```

Here's the jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/amMMV/1/

I'm 100% sure there's something wrong with tags, but I can't find anything.

Answer (score 1):

It is not valid to have a `<div>` be a child of an `<a>`, unless the `<a>` is styled to be a block-level element.

Regardless of that, it is never valid to have any block-level element (such as `<div>`) inside a `<p>` tag.

Comment: Validity never depends on styling. A `<div>` can (in HTML5) be a child of an `<a>` if the `<div>` would have been valid in the parent of the `<a>` element. Also validity is not a particularly good guide to HTML parsing behaviour. For example, `<div>` is not valid in `<span>`, but had `<span>` been used in place of `<p>`, this problem would not have occurred. Nevertheless, your second paragraph is relevant, and close enough.

Comment: Alright, if I have a paragraph full of text and an image aside how should it be done then? If the image is the part of paragraph what's wrong with having it inside? I know img != div, but sometimes you need divs to do, let's say, hover overlay, or caption, or anything else.

Comment: @user1461645 - img is an inline element, div is a block element. You should use a span, not a div to wrap or stand in for the img. You can then style the span element appropriately.